# Combine Micrometer's @Observed and B3 Trace ID value

Tags: spring, micrometer, zipkin, jaeger, observability

The goal is to combine traces of network calls and spans observed by Micrometer. Network calls are observed with B3-headers. Method calls are observed with @Observed annotation. I have a B3-Trace-ID value that I want to combine with observed methods calls.

Not sure where I can inject B3 values into methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find how to set up B3 propagation for Micrometer Tracing in the official docs: https://micrometer.io/docs/tracing

If you use Spring Boot, you can set `management.tracing.propagation.type=b3`.